# Norm adding up residual

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

For FindFit I want to have a norm that just sums up all residuals.

For the sum of absolute values there is `NormFunction -> (Norm[#, 1] &)`, but I don't know how to sum up residuals as they are. I tried to define my own norm but failed, for instance `NormFunction -> (# &)` or `NormFunction -> (Total[#] &)`.

MWE:

```
xdata = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
ydata = {1.2, 2.5, 2.3, 4.3, 5.9, 3.2, 4.9};
data = Transpose [{xdata, ydata}];
value = FindFit[data, a + b x , {a, b}, x, 
  NormFunction -> Total](*(Norm[#,1]&)*)
```

Comment: This succeeds as I would expect it to: `FindFit[data, a x Log[b + c x], {a, b, c}, x, NormFunction -> Total]`. Please show what failed and explain why you think it failed.

Comment: I think this is problematic. As residuals have a sign, they can give a small sum for large residuals. Is this what you want?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for pointing this out. I'm aware of it! :-)

Comment: using just "total" gives this error message: "FindFit::lmnl: The model a+b x is linear in the parameters {a,b}, but a nonlinear method or non-Euclidean norm was specified, so nonlinear methods will be used."

Comment: The message is not an error. It's just informing you that a better method is available. -- The main problem is that the goal is to minimize the norm. With the norm given by `Total`, the minimum will be $-\infty$. This modification of your code gives a proper error: `FindFit[data, b (x + a), {a, b}, x, NormFunction -> Total]`. (Technically, a norm should be positive-definite.)

Comment: Thanks Michael for pointing out this issue! @Daniel: Obviously, I wasn't fully aware of this issue :-/

Comment: This might be what you're after: `FindFit[data, b (x + a), {a, b}, x, NormFunction -> Abs@*Total]`. The norm is positive but not definite. Consequently, there should be infinitely many solutions for which the sum of the residuals is zero. `FindFit` returns one of them along with an error. But it does return one solution. And different starting points return others: `FindFit[data, b (x + a), {{a, -2}, {b, 3}}, x, NormFunction -> Abs@*Total]`

Comment: If you use the linear model and get two values, you can get all of them parametrized by `t` with `value = Thread[{a, b} -> (1 - t) ({a, b} /. value1) + t ({a, b} /. value2)]`. (As long as you understand that I don't know why you want solve such a problem, but it seems a well-defined problem, even if not a common fitting problem.)